# Unable to update maven configuration from nexus repository

Tags: maven-3, nexus

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 from https://devserver/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolutions will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Could not transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 from/to nexus (https://devserver/nexus/content/groups/public): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:PXIX path building failed:sun.security.provider.cerpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I use nexus-professional-2.14.1-01

Settings.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository />
    <interactiveMode />
    <usePluginRegistry />
    <offline />
    <pluginGroups />
    <servers />
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!-- This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://dev.server.net/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies />
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!-- Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!-- all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!-- make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java can't validate the SSL certificate you're using on Nexus. See here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465088-Maven-is-unable-to-connect-to-Nexus-after-configuring-Nexus-to-use-SSL-